# Save JSDOC comments of React components in Webpack build

Tags: reactjs, webpack, jsdoc, webpack-4

I am developing a library of React components. Libraries versions: react - 17, webpack - 4. I encountered difficulties when building a package of React components through Webpack 4 with mode="production"

During development, JSDOC is used to indicate the parameters to accept, so that IDEA highlights and thereby helps developers use the library. However, when mode="production" JSDOC disappears, this is due to minification of component names, removal of comments from the project. Tried various settings and ended up saving the JSDOC comments, but the component names still change

As an example, I give not my project, but a test example

Button.jsx

```
/**
 * @param {String} [className]
 */
const Button = ({ className }) => {
  return (
    <button className={className} />
  );
};

export default Button;
```

index.js

```
export { default as Button } from './Button';
```

webpack.config.js

```
An example of your config for saving JSDOC comments and original component names
```

Has anyone else experienced this or is there a solution to my problem?

[image]

Comment: Why would you generate JSDoc from production code in the first place? How about generating the JSDoc **before** passing your source files into webpack?